# How can I add multiple dict to one multiple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to have a dict like:

```
dict_a= {
 'abc' : {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]},
 'efg' : {'a':[10,11,12], 'b':[13,14,15], 'c':[16,17,18]},
 'hij' : {'a':[21,22,23], 'b':[24,25,26], 'c':[27,28,29]}
}
```

so I separate into 2 dict

```
dict_b = {
 'a': [],
 'b': [],
 'c': []
}

dict_a= {
 'abc': {},
 'efg': {},
 'hij'
}
```

When I put data by using for loop, the last data will cover earlier data. The following is my code:

```
for x in sorted(dict_a):
    for y in sorted(dict_b):
        list= []
        ...
        dict_b[y] = list
    dict_a[x] = dict_b
```

and the result is:

```
dict_a= {
     'abc' : {'a':[21,22,23], 'b':[24,25,26], 'c':[27,28,29]},
     'efg' : {'a':[21,22,23], 'b':[24,25,26], 'c':[27,28,29]},
     'hij' : {'a':[21,22,23], 'b':[24,25,26], 'c':[27,28,29]}
    }
```

My expected result is:

```
dict_a= {
 'abc' : {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]},
 'efg' : {'a':[10,11,12], 'b':[13,14,15], 'c':[16,17,18]},
 'hij' : {'a':[21,22,23], 'b':[24,25,26], 'c':[27,28,29]}
}
```

How can I solve it?

**Update full code:**

```
for market in sorted(MARKET_LUT):
        for type in sorted(STOCK_TYPE_LUT):
            try:
                list = []
                data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=' ', header=None, names=['code', 'name'])
                list = data.code.tolist()
                dict_b [type] = list 

            except Exception as e:
                traceback.print_exc()
                err = sys.exc_info()[1]
                LOG_write_log(LOG_ERROR, str(err))    

        dict_a[x] = dict_b
```

Comment: Is the result your desired result? Or is that somehow wrong.

Comment: Don't modify your dicts when looping over. Copy (from copy import deepcopy) or use other ones.

Comment: `dict_a[x] = dict_b` adds a reference to the same dict at every loop. Create a new one in each loop if you want to reference different dict

Comment: @chrisz this is not my expected result, my expected result is :dict_a= {
 'abc' : {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]},
 'efg' : {'a':[10,11,12], 'b':[13,14,15], 'c':[16,17,18]},
 'hij' : {'a':[21,22,23], 'b':[24,25,26], 'c':[27,28,29]}
} but i get dict_a= {
     'abc' : {'a':[21,22,23], 'b':[24,25,26], 'c':[27,28,29]},
     'efg' : {'a':[21,22,23], 'b':[24,25,26], 'c':[27,28,29]},
     'hij' : {'a':[21,22,23], 'b':[24,25,26], 'c':[27,28,29]}
    }

Comment: @Sylvain Biehler so, do you means that i need to add `dict={}` for each `x` ?

Comment: @shadowdk `new_dict = dict()`  (`{}` is a set)

Comment: I'm confused. What is your **input** ? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49922911/edit) to clarify.

Comment: Please add the missing `...` code in the inner-most `for` loop that you left out of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
for x in sorted(dict_a):
    for y in sorted(dict_b):
        list= []
        ...
        dict_b[y] = list
    dict_a[x] = dict_b
```

by

```
for x in sorted(dict_a):
    new_dict = dict()
    for y in sorted(dict_b):
        list= []
        ...
        new_dict[y] = list
    dict_a[x] = new_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the exact result you want, but this seems close and illustrates how to avoid the problem you have about the last data covering earlier data.

```
from pprint import pprint

dict_b = {
    'a': [],
    'b': [],
    'c': []
}

dict_a= {
    'abc': {},
    'efg': {},
    'hij': {}
}

count = 1
for x in sorted(dict_a):
    dict_temp = dict_b.copy()  # Copy empty dict.
    for y in sorted(dict_b):
        lst = list(range(count, count+3))
        dict_temp[y] = lst
        count += 3
    dict_a[x] = dict_temp

pprint(dict_a)
```

Result:

```
{'abc': {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]},
 'efg': {'a': [10, 11, 12], 'b': [13, 14, 15], 'c': [16, 17, 18]},
 'hij': {'a': [19, 20, 21], 'b': [22, 23, 24], 'c': [25, 26, 27]}}
```